# StorageContainer.OpenFile access denied (Windows store app)

Tags: c#, xna, windows-store-apps, windows, access-denied

I'm writing a game in XNA for Windows store and I'm trying to load saved game data

```
//Open file 
Stream stream = storageContainer.OpenFile( filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read );
```

Which gives me this error:

> Additional information: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Weird thing is that I'm able to write to the location just fine with this:

```
//Save
using( Stream stream = storageContainer.CreateFile( filename ) )
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer( typeof( SaveData ) );
    serializer.Serialize( stream, saveData );
}
```

I went as far as giving "Everyone" full access to appdata folder but that didn't help.

What causes this problem? How do I fix it? Or is there a better way of doing this?